Why does moving to the east of a given geographic origin vary latitude?
I am trying to compute the longitude and latitude of points given an origin point of known longitude and latitude, and (easting, northing) coordinate offsets from that origin (in meters). I know this is known as the forward geodetic problem and can be solved used the pyproj.Geod.fwd function. So I wrote the following function:
import numpy as np
import pyproj


WGS84_GEOD = pyproj.Geod(ellps="wgs84")


def en2geographic(easting: NDArray, northing: NDArray, wgs84_origin: dict[str, float]):
    """
    Convert E, N coordinates to latitude and longitude.

    Note: East and North are defined by the azimuth, i.e. the signed angle between the
    (origin, North pole) axis and the (origin, point) axis. The North is the direction
    such that azimuth = 0. In other words, if `northing` is zero, the latitude remains
    constant.

    Args:
        easting (NDArray): easting in meters, relative to the origin
        northing (NDArray): northing in meters, relative to the origin
        wgs84_origin (dict[str, float]): dictionary with keys "longitude" and "latitude"
        representing the origin point, in degrees

    Returns:
    latitude (NDArray): latitude in degrees
    longitude (NDArray): longitude in degrees

    """
    fw_azimuth = np.where(northing != 0.0, np.arctan2(easting, northing), np.pi / 2)
    dist = np.linalg.norm(np.stack((easting, northing), axis=-1), axis=-1)
    longitude, latitude, _ = WGS84_GEOD.fwd(
        lons=np.full_like(dist, fill_value=wgs84_origin["longitude"]),
        lats=np.full_like(dist, fill_value=wgs84_origin["latitude"]),
        az=np.rad2deg(fw_azimuth),
        dist=dist,
    )

    return latitude, longitude

As you can see in the docstring, my understanding is that this function should output the same latitude if you don't move along the North direction, because going East should be equivalent to moving in a circle of constant longitude on the surface of the Earth. However, this is not what I observe in the results, for instance:
origin = {"longitude": 1.5, "latitude": 49.0}  # degrees
easting = np.array([1, 2, 3, 300000])  # meters
northing = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])

latitude, longitude = en2geographic(easting, northing, origin)
print(latitude)  # [48.99999999999919, 48.99999999999676, 48.999999999992724, 48.927223721247195]
print(longitude)  # [1.5000136664683779, 1.500027332936756, 1.5000409994051338, 5.595963333082087]

We can see that the latitude clearly varies for large values of easting, despite northing not varying at all. The effect is much more noticeable for larger distances, for example here's a QGIS visualization using the Globe Builder plugin


I don't think this is due to numerical errors as the azimuth is always exactly equal to 90 degrees. I think this is a misunderstanding on my part of the forward geodetic problem. Am I right in my assumption that not moving in the North direction should result in constant latitude ? I have come across this question where someone encountered the same problem as me, except in my case I know the bearing  (azimuth) angle.

Break out a soccer ball and try to tape a piece of yarn across it. The fastest route  between two longitudes along a line of latitude is not along the line of latitude -- The "great circle" route actually tucks up toward the nearest pole and back down again.

Thanks for you comment @Vince, it is true that since a constant-latitude circle can never be a great circle (except at the equator), the latitude would slightly vary between my "purely eastwards" points. So, the implication is that it isn't possible to go straight East in a straight line (that is, a line of constant azimuth) ? For instance, a car cannot go straight East without ever so slightly steering the wheels ? I am really confused about the definition of "eastwards"...
